# Preview not display straight away

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click on my button's at top of textarea it opens either a hyperlink modal or a image insert modal shown in codepen example below.

I can create and insert links and images fine.

How ever when I create the links or image and click save on modal the preview does not show straight away I have to press a key in textarea to see new changes in preview.

> **Question:** When I add a new hyperlink or image from my bootstrap modal
>   and click save how can I make sure the changes show up in preview
>   straight away. Using **showdown.js**

**[CODEPEN EXAMPLE](http://codepen.io/wolfgang1983/pen/YNzqbN)**

Script

```
$("#message").on('keyup paste copy change', function() {
var text = document.getElementById('message').value,
      target = document.getElementById('showdown'),
      converter = new showdown.Converter({parseImgDimensions: true}),
      html = converter.makeHtml(text);

    target.innerHTML = html;
});
```

Full Script

```
$('#button-link').on('click', function() {
    $('#myLink').modal('show');
});

$('#button-image').on('click', function() {
    $('#myImage').modal('show');
}); 

$('#button-smile').on('click', function() {
    $('#mySmile').modal('show');
});

$('#myLink').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    var textarea = document.getElementById("message");
    var len = textarea.value.length;
    var start = textarea.selectionStart;
    var end = textarea.selectionEnd;
    var selectedText = textarea.value.substring(start, end);
    $('#link_title').val(selectedText);
    $('#link_url').val('http://');
});  

$('#myImage').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    $("#image_url").attr("placeholder", "http://www.example.com/image.png");
});

$("#save-image").on('click', function(e) {
    var textarea = document.getElementById("message");
    var len = textarea.value.length;
    var start = textarea.selectionStart;
    var end = textarea.selectionEnd;
    var selectedText = textarea.value.substring(start, end);
    var counter = findAvailableNumber(textarea);

    var replace_word = '![enter image description here]' + '[' + counter + ']';

    if (counter == 1) {

        if ($('input#image_width').val().length > 0) {
            var add_link = '\n\n' + '   [' + counter + ']: ' + $('#image_url').val() + ' =' + $('input#image_width').val() + 'x' + $('input#image_height').val();
        } else {
            var add_link = '\n\n' + '   [' + counter + ']: ' + $('#image_url').val();
        }

    } else {
        var add_link = '\n' + '   [' + counter + ']: ' + $('#image_url').val();
    }

    textarea.value = textarea.value.substring(0, start) + replace_word + textarea.value.substring(end,len) + add_link;
}); 

$("#save-link").on('click', function(e) {
    var textarea = document.getElementById("message");
    var len = textarea.value.length;
    var start = textarea.selectionStart;
    var end = textarea.selectionEnd;
    var selectedText = textarea.value.substring(start, end);
    var counter = findAvailableNumber(textarea);

    if ($('#link_title').val().length > 0) {
        var replace_word = '[' + $('#link_title').val() + ']' + '[' + counter + ']';
    } else {
        var replace_word = '[enter link description here]' + '[' + counter + ']';
    }

    if (counter == 1) {
        var add_link = '\n\n' + '   [' + counter + ']: ' + $('#link_url').val();
    } else {
        var add_link = '\n' + '   [' + counter + ']: ' + $('#link_url').val();
    }

    textarea.value = textarea.value.substring(0, start) + replace_word + textarea.value.substring(end,len) + add_link;
});

function findAvailableNumber(textarea){
    var number = 1;

    var a = textarea.value;

    if(a.indexOf('[1]') > -1){

        //Find lines with links

        var matches = a.match(/(^|\n)\s*\[\d+\]:/g);

        //Find corresponding numbers

        var usedNumbers = matches.map(function(match){
            return parseInt(match.match(/\d+/)[0]); }
        );

        //Find first unused number

        var number = 1;

        while(true){

            if(usedNumbers.indexOf(number) === -1){

                //Found unused number

                return number;
            }

            number++;
        }
    }

    return number;
}

$("#message").on('keyup paste copy change', function() {
var text = document.getElementById('message').value,
      target = document.getElementById('showdown'),
      converter = new showdown.Converter({parseImgDimensions: true}),
      html = converter.makeHtml(text);

    target.innerHTML = html;
});

$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just trigger the `keyup` event at the end of the `$("#save-link").on('click', function(e) {});`

I assume as jQuery setting value doesn't trigger any of the related events set on `$("#message")`

```
$("#message").trigger('keyup');
```

Just tested on the codepen and works fine,

```
$("#save-link").on('click', function(e) {
    //All your code
    // ....

    $("#message").trigger('keyup');
});
```

I hope this helps !!

Comment: Tried that on my save - image no luck

Comment: Does that mean it works on save link? Could you try the `change` event

Comment: Did you try it on save-image or just the save-link

Comment: Let me check the save image, it worked on the save link

Comment: The `$("#message").trigger('change');` one works fine on save-image

Comment: Great, I hope my answer helped you. Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks for your advice about `trigger()`